# Prestashop usng webservice to create multi shop and auto include the shop as shop association

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.6

I use Webservice to create a shop for multi shop in PS 1.6. the shop created successfully, but the main webservice account is not attaching the new shop that created.

Is there a way to update the web service programatically so the new shop is include as shop association?

The only way I found is to add the new shop id in ps_webservice_account_shop table, but I thing this is not good approach